# What do you do with the pads that are not a real pin on a PCB layout?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am using the [SIM8055](https://gct.co/files/drawings/sim8055.pdf?v=d981fce7-2124-4bb1-93e5-5143cd6d9a19) connector in one of my PCB designs. The datasheet shows there are 9 pads that you should include in the PCB design (C1, C2, C3, CD, C5, C6, C7, no name pad on the right, no name pad on the left):

[image]

I understand what to do with al the other pads, but the datasheet doesn't specify anything about what to do with the left and right pads. I don't think these pads are actual pins, so I am assuming they are just there for mechanical support. Am I supposed to connect these to ground? Connect them together? Leave them floating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to do whatever you want with them, all your options are good depending on what you want to achieve.

The pads are just metal wings folded out from the protective metal shell.

Note the data sheet does mark these as solder area, so best option is to have solder pads for mechanical support.

As the metal wings are likely folded from the same metal cover sheet, the pads are already electrically connected together through the component.

So you can leave both pins floating if you want the metal shell to float.

If you want to ground the metal shell, connect one of the pin, or even better, both pins to ground.